# how to undo the action DayPilot.Scheduler on event Resized without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, daypilot

How to undo the action `DayPilot.Scheduler` on event `Resized` on the last event i saved without reloading the page?

Here is my code:

```
dp.onEventResized = function (args) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to edit this?')) {
        --do some code --
    }
    else
    {             
        window.location.reload();
        //undo the last event..
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use *onEventResize* to display the confirmation dialog. This event is called before the default action (while *onEventResized* is called after it). You can cancel the default action using args.preventDefault():

```
dp.onEventResize = function (args) {
  if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to edit this?')) {
  {             
    args.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

Keep the original action in the onEventResized handler:

```
dp.onEventResized = function (args) {
   // submit changes
};
```

Comment: Sir. Is it posible to use args.preventDefault(); on onEventMove to cancel action?